# How to show full day name with command of e.g. Jul 16 1991

Tags: date

I found out that `date --date 'Jul 16 1991'` has an complete output, but I only want the terminal to show the name of the day e.g. Monday. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
date --date 'Jul 16 1991' +%A
```

See [`man date`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date), specifically the section on output formatting.

Comment: Ah I see, I did tried `date --date %A 'Jul 16 1991'` but did not work, I get the order now. Thank you

Comment: @F4LLCON Also note that the `+` is important.